# Is $(a/b)-1$ approximately equal to $\log_e (a/b)$

Tags: logarithms, approximation

I was reading an article where in one of the steps we were trying to calculate the daily return. It said

```
Return = (a / b) – 1
```

It then said, this equation can be approximated to:

```
Return = Log e (a/b)
```

Could someone explain a proof around how these are equal? Why $\log_e$ (and not $\log$ base of another value)?

Comment: One has the Taylor series$$
\log x = (x - 1) - \frac{{(x - 1)^2 }}{2} + \frac{{(x - 1)^3 }}{3} -  \cdots 
$$ which converges for $0 <x <2$. It follows that $\log x \approx x - 1$ when $x$ is close to $1$.

Comment: I suspect your divisions may be upside down and instead should be today's price divided by yesterday's price

Comment: @henry thanks for pointing out. Editing question to remove details not directly related to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained by the Taylor's theorem, expanding to the first order:

$$\log(1+x)\approx \log(1+x)_{x=0}+\left(\log(1+x)\right)'_{x=0}x=\frac x{1+0}=x.$$

For logarithms in other bases, it suffices to apply the conversion factor. (The natural logarithm is used because no factor is required by the derivative.)

With $x:=\dfrac ab-1$,

$$\log\left(\frac ab\right)\approx \frac ab-1.$$

The closer to $1$ the ratio, the better the approximation.

In fact, you are replacing the curve by its tangent:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take it in the other direction
$$\log \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\log \left(1+\frac{a-b}{b}\right)\approx \frac{a-b}{b}=\frac{a}{b}-1$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is this some log rule?
log(1+(− / )) ≈ (−)/

Comment: @noi.m. When $x\ll 1$  then $\log(1+x)\sim x$

Answer (score 0):

Set $x:=\log_e (a/b)$, $a/b>0$;

Then

$(a/b) =e^x= 1+x+x^2/2! +...;$

$(a/b) =$

$1+\log_e (a/b) + O((\log_e (a/b))^2)$.